# How to get xpath of a select tag with option in static dropdown

Tags: c#, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, html-select

How to get the xpath for the second element in the dropdown from below html
I am using C# with specflow and selenium

In the UI there is a static dropdown under the property type and within it have two options Residential and Business I need to find the second one.

```
<select class= "form-control ng-pristine ng-empty ng-invalid-required ng-touched" type="text" 
id="propertyType" name="propertyTypr" ng-modal="lead.currentLeadContact.IsResidential" required 
style>
<option value="? object:null ?"></option>
<option value="true">Residintial</option>
<option value="false">Business</option>
</select>
```

Already tried with

```
//select[@id='prorpertyType']/option[@value='false' and . ='Business']
```

and

```
//select[@id='propertyType' and @value='1'] same xpath with value 0 and 2
```

I appreciate if anyone could help me with that.

Answer (score 0):

To select the `<option>` with text as **Business** you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/dotnet/html/T_OpenQA_Selenium_Support_UI_WebDriverWait.htm) for the `ElementToBeClickable()` and you can use either of the [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using *CssSelector* and `SelectByValue()`:

  ```
  new SelectElement(new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(20)).Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(By.CssSelector("select#propertyType[name='propertyTypr']")))).SelectByValue("false");
  ```
- Using *XPath* and `SelectByText()`:

  ```
  new SelectElement(new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(20)).Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(By.CssSelector("//select[@id='propertyType' and @name='propertyTypr']")))).SelectByText("Business");
  ```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to find the option that have the text is "Business", you can try this:

```
string optionText = "Business";

string xpath = "//option[text()='"+ optionText +"']"
```